# Как выгрузить несколько одинаковых ключей из разных словарей внутри одного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Есть один список, количество словарей внутри него не ограниченно.
То есть может быть как и два словаря внутри списка, так и 200

Пример списка:

```
[{'user': 565656, 'orders': 989898}, {'user_id': 565656, 'orders': 564898}]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне вытащить `orders` из нескольких словарей внутри списка и создать из них новый список, допустим ['989898','564898']

Ответ на вопрос
`res = [x.get("orders") for x in data]`

Спасибо

Comment: `res = [x.get("orders") for x in data]`

Comment: Благодарю уважаемый. Спасибо

Comment: вам бы неплохо выучить терминологию. то, что вы называете листами у вас - это словари. то, что вы называете массивом - список. а понятия "лист" в русском языке для питона вообще не существует - это будет "список".

Comment: Спасибо! Я обязательно учту